# How to ignore error messages in bash on Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-9.10, bash, redirection

I'm trying to show the number of lines, words and characters of all configuration files in *`/etc/*conf`* (with command *`wc`*).

How can I modify the command (or commandline) to not view the error messages?

Comment: If Roy's answer below doesn't provide what you want, could you provide the command you're trying so we can get an idea of what's not working properly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
wc /etc/*conf 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 4):

i don't have access to a shell right now, but you can try something like

```
cat /etc/*.conf 2> /dev/null | wc -l
```

That should redirect all the errors and leave the output to be passed to wc

Comment: this won't allow *wc* to output word/line/char counts per-file, if that's what the OP wants.  it will get the *total* of all `/etc/*conf` files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually just redirect the standard output to /dev/null to ignore the output, but this is not good practice when writing shell scripts

Try use -q instead to run the shell in quite mode, which will produce less output.

This might not be relevant to the question, but just FYI.